# Url Rewriting using Intelligencia.UrlRewriter in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting

I am using Intelligencia.UrlRewriter in my asp.net website.

I am using below rewrite for redirecting to page.

```
<rewrite url="~/Unlock" to="~/Default1.aspx" />
<rewrite url="~/UnlockUser" to="~/Default2.aspx" />
```

My problem is that if I use UnlockUser in my url vent though it is redirecting to "Default1.aspx" page instead if "Default2.aspx" page.

Can someone please help me for this url rewriting?

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0):

Change the order of rules, like this:

```
<rewrite url="~/UnlockUser" to="~/Default2.aspx" />
<rewrite url="~/Unlock" to="~/Default1.aspx" />
```